# Mat-tab load inner component after selected tab

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-material

I am using `Mat-tab`  in Angular material 7.2.1 version

Each tab contains a different component.

**Like below:**

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <span>Map</span>
    </ng-template>
      <app-health-education-map></app-health-education-map>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <span>Form</span>
    </ng-template>
    <app-health-education-form></app-health-education-form>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Using `ngOnInit` event in inner component to load the data, hits when the page is loaded and **not when tab selected**.

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: play with `tabIndex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to trigger change in tab:

```
<mat-tab-group selectedIndex="0" (selectedTabChange)="changeTab($event)">
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <span>search</span>
    </ng-template>
      <app-search></app-search>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <span>home</span>
    </ng-template>
    <app-home  *ngIf="tabIndex === 1"></app-home>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

ts:

```
tabIndex = 0 ;

changeTab(event){
   this.tabIndex = event.index;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tab-example-cha7ee)
the name will be appear after 5 seconds of initializing the inner component.